# Send S3 files as .zip as a response in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3

I'm trying to send a zip file of certain items in my amazon S3 main bucket with a response on an HTTP request. Since I'm fairly new with express.js and I didn't see any specific way to do it manually, I am using s3-zip, which has no specific instructions on how to send the file in the response, but rather outputs it in a directory:

```
const output = fs.createWriteStream(join(__dirname, 'use-s3-zip.zip'))

s3Zip
  .archive({ region: region, bucket: bucket}, folder, [file1, file2, file3, file4])
  .pipe(output)
```

Here is my slight adaptation to the code:

```
app.get('/files', (request, response) => {
  const objectIds = request.body.objectIds
  const folder = request.body.folder

  response.set('content-type', 'application/zip')

  s3Zip
    .archive({ s3: s3, bucket: aws_bucket_name }, folder, objectIds)
    .pipe(response)

  s3Zip.on('end', () => {
    console.log('ended');
    response.end();
  })
});
```

However, s3Zip.on is not defined.

Has anybody 1) used this dependency in this way before and could point at how to make it work or 2) has another idea to accomplish my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just redirect to a signed URL on your bucket instead?  Save the load and bandwidth for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use: `response.end()`, `.pipe` will take care of that.

`s3Zip` does not have `.on` method, but the stream created by `s3Zip.archive`

```
app.get('/files', (request, response) => {
  const objectIds = request.body.objectIds
  const folder = request.body.folder

  response.set('content-type', 'application/zip')

  s3Zip
    .archive({ s3: s3, bucket: aws_bucket_name }, folder, objectIds)
    .pipe(response)

});
```

or

```
app.get('/files', (request, response) => {
  const objectIds = request.body.objectIds
  const folder = request.body.folder

  response.set('content-type', 'application/zip')

  const archive = s3Zip
    .archive({ s3: s3, bucket: aws_bucket_name }, folder, objectIds)


  archive.on('error', (e) => {
     res.status(500).send(e.message);
  });

  archive.on('end', () => {
     console.log('archive created');
  });

  archive.pipe(response);

});
```

Comment: So when I tried that the response timed out and was never sent

Comment: it may be taking a lot of time to create the zip, is it a big file?

Comment: Not really, but I figured that I'm getting an error that I wasn't catching on s3-zip.. It seems I was unauthenticated.

Comment: Yeah didn't mentioned that, since I though you already had that in your code and the download was actually working.

Comment: If you by any chance know how to authenticate (even though I'm not using the s3 object here) and add the code to capture errors, I'd be happy to upvote your answer

Comment: If you show your whole code, and what s3 is, then yes.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande how to make it work to download multiple zip archives? I want to be able to download all of the folders as zip archives?